# substring methods java

Tags: java, substring

So I've been working on this portion of code for a while and I need help. I need to use a substring to print out a user input vertically. I think I am close but just need one litttle tip I think.

```
         public static void method3(){
   System.out.print("Method 3"); 
 Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
  String height = console.nextLine(); 

   System.out.println(" Type in a word to be printed vertically!");
  String str = console.nextLine();

  System.out.println(str.charAt(height) + " ");
```

Comment: Must you use `substring`? `String#charAt` and `String#toCharArray` would be substantially easier.

Comment: To call _substring()_ on a String you will need to pass some parameters.  The parameters must be enclosed with parentheses.

Comment: str.substring is wrong. you have to specify the index location http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int)

Comment: I need it to print out a user's input one letter per line vertically. All it prints out is the number values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String.substring()` is a method, not a field, meaning you need to call `str.substring()` rather than simply `str.substring`. Further, the substring method takes parameters  - you have to tell it the specific substring you want in the form of which indexes within the string. `str.substring(0, 2)` would print characters 0 and 1 (the upper bound is not included). For your purposes, `str.substring(height, height+1)` would work...

IF you have to use substring.

I would recommend using `str.charAt(height)`, which accomplishes the same goal.

EDIT (based on your edit) : 
1)  You have height defined as a String, then you call str.charAt(height). The charAt() method takes an int parameter - if you give it 6, it will give you the charater at index 6 (i.e. the seventh letter) in the string. Knowing that, it doesn't make any sense to pass a String in as a parameter, does it?

2) You're still going to need a loop to accomplish this. Something like:

```
String str = console.nextLine();
     for (int height = 0; height < str.length; height++) {            
         System.out.println(str.charAt(height);   
     }
```

Does that make sense? Let me know if I need to walk you through what we're doing in this.

Comment: Okay I am trying what your saying, but there is an error message:      System.out.print("Method 3"); 
  Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
 String height = console.nextLine(); 
  
  System.out.println(" Type in a word to be printed vertically!");
  String str = console.nextLine();
 
  System.out.println(str.substring(str.length(height, height + 1)) + " ");
  }

Comment: ahhh somehow I messed up the format and it screwed the code up

Comment: public static void method3(){
  System.out.print("Method 3"); 
  Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
 String height = console.nextLine(); 
  
  System.out.println(" Type in a word to be printed vertically!");
  String str = console.next();
 System.out.println(str.charAt(height) + " ");

Comment: `String height = console.nextLine()`... That needs to be `String str = ...`.

Comment: Why don't you post your updated code as an edit to your original question, it's difficult for me to work with it down here.

Comment: okay and it keeps telling me that the char is not accepted with a string ?

Comment: Yes, that's because you've defined height as a String. the `String.charAt()` method takes an `int` as a parameter. Given what we've told you about how that method works, it doesn't make any sense to pass a String as a parameter to it, does it?

Comment: I just posted the update...I'm pretty new to java (obviously) haha and I've been working on this so long that I'm not thinking properly haha sorry.

Comment: Yeah, look at the comment I just posted. You have `height` defined as a String, then you call `str.charAt(height)`. The `charAt()` method takes an int parameter - if you give it 6, it will give you the charater at index 6 (i.e. the seventh letter) in the string. You were actually a lot closer before-  I'm going to edit my answer, look at it in a minute.

Comment: WOW!! it works now! I used your code and tweaked some of the crap I had and it finally works!! Thanks a lot! Like I said, I'm new to java so this kind of stuff is an issue for me at times haha. Have a good night!

Answer (score 2):

Simple option is-

```
System.out.println(str.charAt(height) + " ");
```

Or you can convert to char array and iterate through it.

Comment: public static void method3(){
      System.out.print("Method 3"); 
       Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
      String height = console.nextLine(); 
  
       System.out.println(" Type in a word to be printed vertically!");
             String str = console.next();
         System.out.println(str.charAt(height) + " ");